# Using findOne() to query an email address

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I am trying to query an email address in my database that matches with the user input. I am using `findOne()`, but somehow I am having issues with it:

```
Profile.findOne({emailaddress : req.body.emailaddress},   function(matchinguser) {
            console.dir("matching user" + matchinguser);
            Profile.create(req.params.all(), function (err, profile) {
                console.dir(profile);
                if (err) {
                    req.session.flash = {
                        err: err
                    }
                    return res.redirect('/profile/new')
                }
                res.redirect('/profile')
                req.session.flash = {};
            }) //profile created
        }) //findone
```

Comment: Your `findOne()` callback function is missing the `err` parameter, it only has the result (`matchinguser` param). Try adding it `Profile.findOne({emailaddress : req.body.emailaddress},   function(err, matchinguser) { ..` and see how that goes.

Comment: *"but somehow I am having issues with it:"* expand upon said "issues"

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few issues with the code as it stands. The missing "err" in callback is one of them but also I think you should be using "exec". Right now your function is trying to execute as you would format a native query in sails.js. Here is my recommended adjusted code:

```
Profile.findOne({emailaddress : req.body.emailaddress}).exec(err,function(matchinguser) {
     //Handle errors  
     if (err){ return res.negotiate(err);}

     //Handle success
     //I assume do some checks on the user found e.g. return them or if not found create the user
    if(!matchinguser){
     //No user found so redirect back
     return res.redirect('/profile');}
    //Rest of your code can go in here if needed I've just redirected you back for now.
    return res.redirect('/profile/);
    });
```

I would also be careful of using req.body.emailaddress directly in your query without checking it over, but thats just me.